# Как изменить сообщение при активации аккаунта в Ultimate member?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

В плагине для WP Ultimate member есть проблема. Когда подключена двусторонняя верификация по почте после регистрации перекидывает на сообщение:
"Спасибо за регистрацию. Прежде чем Вы сможете зайти на сайт, необходимо активировать свою учётную запись, перейдя по ссылке активации в письме, которое только что отправлено Вам."

Необходимо немного подправить это сообщение, добавить строчку "Проверьте спам". Я пробовал изменить файл .po и .mo перевод - в переводе меняет, строчку добавляет, а на сайте нет.

Потом пробовал в коде заменить
php, но тоже ничего не выходит, мне бы в идеале чтобы после того как человек нажал "регистрироваться" его бы перенаправляло туда, на другую страницу, где была бы информация о спаме и тд

```
array(
                'id'            => '_um_checkmail_action',
                'type'          => 'select',
                'label'         => __( 'Action to be taken after registration', 'ultimate-member' ),
                'tooltip'   => __( 'Select what action is taken after a person registers on your site. Depending on the status you can redirect them to their profile, a custom url or show a custom message', 'ultimate-member' ),
                'value'         => ! empty( $role['_um_checkmail_action'] ) ? __( $role['_um_checkmail_action'], 'ultimate-member' ) : array(),
                'options'       => array(
                    'show_message'  => __( 'Show custom message', 'ultimate-member' ),
                    'redirect_url'  => __( 'Redirect to URL', 'ultimate-member' ),
                ),
                'conditional'   => array( '_um_status', '=', 'checkmail' )
            ),
            array(
                'id'        => '_um_checkmail_message',
                'type'      => 'textarea',
                'label'         => __( 'Personalize the custom message', 'ultimate-member' ),
                'value'         => ! empty( $role['_um_checkmail_message'] ) ? __( $role['_um_checkmail_message'], 'ultimate-member' ) : __('Спасибо за регистрацию. Прежде чем Вы сможете зайти на сайт, необходимо активировать свою учётную запись, перейдя по ссылке активации в письме, которое только что отправлено Вам. Проверьте в почтовом ящике папки «Промоакции» и «Спам». В зависимости от вашего почтового клиента письмо с подтверждением может попасть в одну из этих папок.','ultimate-member'),
                
                'conditional'   => array( '_um_checkmail_action', '=', 'show_message' )
            ),
            array(
                'id'        => '_um_checkmail_url',
                'type'      => 'text',
                'label'         => __( 'Set Custom Redirect URL', 'ultimate-member' ),
                'value'         => ! empty( $role['_um_checkmail_url'] ) ? __( $role['_um_checkmail_url'], 'ultimate-member' ) : '',
                'conditional'   => array( '_um_checkmail_action', '=', 'redirect_url' )
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

> Я пробовал изменить файл .po и .mo перевод - в переводе меняет, строчку добавляет, а на сайте нет.

Менять надо в лангпаке. Но не блокнотом в .po, а специальными средствами, создающими .mo. Причем и этот лангпак подключать отдельно, во избежание перезаписи. https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/ поможет со всем этим.

> Я пробовал изменить файл .po и .mo перевод - в переводе меняет, строчку добавляет, а на сайте нет.

Никогда не трогай файлы плагинов.